# Choosing what pojo to use based on the user role on an edit request

Tags: java, spring, roles

So I am wondering what the best way to process an edit request based on a user role.

Say I have the following PostMapping:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/edit")
public ResponseEntity<String> editIoc(@RequestBody GeneralPojoAllFields editRequest)
```

the GeneralPojoAllFields looks like this:

```
public class GeneralPojoAllFields {    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String onlyAdminCanEditField;
}
```

This is the pojo the the admin will be able to use and that will eventually get mapped into the entity class to be saved to the database. However, if we have a regular user who wants to edit it and hypothetically they aren't restricted in the UI would that design work? What I am currently thinking is I would have a user pojo like so:

```
public class UserPojo {    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

After the request mapping comes we check if the user is either regular user or an admin. If it is a regular user we just map the GeneralPojoAllFields to the UserPojo and it wont map over the onlyAdminCanEditField and continue from there.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as the one that helped you with the green arrow. Otherwise this post remains open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your backend should be as independent of the UI as possible. So, access control in UI is a good to have design, but you should not depend upon it.

Now, coming back to your question, yes you can use `SecurityContextHolder` to find out if the user if regular user/admin. However, if its possible, I would suggest making two controllers, one for admin and one for regular user. Use `@PreAuthorize` on the admin controller to restrict access. Having two separate controllers will increase readability of your code tremendously.

Additionally, you can call the same service class method from both the controllers. And since you already have two POJO classes, you can use them in `@RequestBody` and let Spring take care of the mappings for you.

Comment: I was thinking about this too. I was curious if there is a way to rewrite the url's that are coming in from the request based on the role. For example if both a user and admin would make a request for /edit but internally we would make that request either to user/edit or admin/edit.

Comment: Yes you can. Just call the appropriate _service method_ from the controller. So, if you have these service methods, `editServiceForUser()`  and `editServiceForAdmin()`; what you can do is, in your `/edit` controller call either of them basis role of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what you think a better way would be. It also depends a bit on your data source. But as there is no information on that here, I would suggest that a better way to do yours is by inheritance.

Make `UserPojo` the super class and `GeneralPojoAllFields` extend that class.

UserPojo.java:

```
public class UserPojo {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public UserPojo() {}

    public UserPojo(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

GeneralPojoAllFields.java:

```
public class GeneralPojoAllFields extends UserPojo {
    private String onlyAdminCanEditField;

    public String getOnlyAdminCanEditField() {
        return onlyAdminCanEditField;
    }

    public void setOnlyAdminCanEditField(String onlyAdminCanEditField) {
        this.onlyAdminCanEditField = onlyAdminCanEditField;
    }

    public GeneralPojoAllFields() {}

    public GeneralPojoAllFields(String firstName, String lastName, String onlyAdminCanEditField) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.onlyAdminCanEditField = onlyAdminCanEditField;
    }
}
```

App.java:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserPojo up1 = new UserPojo();
        up1.setFirstName("MyFirstName");
        up1.setLastName("MyLastName");

        GeneralPojoAllFields gpaf1 = new GeneralPojoAllFields();
        gpaf1.setFirstName("MyFirstName");
        gpaf1.setLastName("MyLastName");
        gpaf1.setOnlyAdminCanEditField("yes");
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Socrates, thanks for the advice. In this case, what would the request mapping be for my api call? Would it still be GeneralPojoAllFields? If I had a requestbody of {"firstName" : "bob", "lastName" : "sagget", "onlyAdminCanEditField" : "secret"} would it set all those fields in the GeneralPojo if i used it as part of the @RequetstBody? Now I am back to my dilemma of what if it is a regular user.

Comment: It depends on what you are requesting. The example JSON you mention would be a ´GeneralPojoAllFields´ object and not a ´GeneralPojo´ object. Interally they are connected, but externally they appear like two objects, because they have different signatures. If you request the JSON sting you mention and put it into a ´GeneralPojo´ object, you either get an error because deserialization fails, or you just ignore the ´onlyAdminCanEditField´ and can only access the ´firstName´ and ´lastName´.